# AWS IAM Policy: Tag only untagged resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We have an AWS user, who should be able to `Create` different resources like `Instances`, `Volumes` and `SecurityGroups` but not modify resources that are not part of its project.

For this purpose we allow the creation of resources and let the user `CreateTags` his resources with a `Project` tag and a value of `<user's team name here>`. He should not be able to tag already tagged resources and so, not the resources of other teams. (Every single resource is properly tagged here).

I have created a policy with statement:

```
[...]
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:CreateTags",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Project": "true"
            }
        }
    }
[...]
```

If I use the Policy Simulator by AWS, I am **allowed** to call `CreateTags` on a resource without a `Project` tag.
If I simulate it with setting a `Project` tag, the action is **denied** just as expected.

Unforunately, if I use the same actions from the AWS CLI with this policy, `CreateTags` is **allowed** every time. Even if the tag is already set and even on foreign instances the user should not be able to modify:

as user with mentioned policy

```
aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name "test-sg" --description "test" # creation of a new resource

(AWS answer){
    "GroupId": "sg-4a3151aa"
}
```

.

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources sg-4a31513c --tags Key=Project,Value=web-performance # this should work, ResourceTag Project is Null
(success)

aws ec2 create-tags --resources sg-4a31513c --tags Key=Project,Value=web-performance # should *not* work, ResourceTag Project is already set and not Null
(success)
```

As you can see, it works both times and it works also on foreign Projects where the tag is already set.

I also tried it with

```
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Project": "*"
            }
        }
```

This behaves exactly like the "Null" Condition, even in the Policy Simulator.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this against an EC2 instance rather than a security group? Would be interesting to see if the policy works in that scenario.

Comment: @jarmod yes, behaves exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon EC2 has partial support for resource-level permissions. At the time of writing, the CreateTags action does **not** support resource-level permissions. You can see the list of actions that support resource-level permissions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html).

You can verify this by changing your policy to specify StopInstances (which supports resource-level permissions) in place of CreateTags. Your IAM user will only be able to stop an EC2 instance if the instance does *not* have a Project tag. Alternatively, if you change the Null condition to false, then the IAM user will only be able to stop an EC2 instance if the instance *does* have a Project tag.

So, your policy will presumably be correct at some point in the future, when CreateTags supports resource-level permissions.